# Sites' Guest Access to the Support API?

Tags: api, force.com-sites

The Summer '16 Release added the option to check `Guest Access to the Support API` on Sites.  I can't find any specific Salesforce API called "Support API".  What API access does this allow?  Salesforce SOAP API access?  Access to Remote Objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_log_case.htm

> To ensure your guest community users can securely log cases directly
>   through contact support, enable Guest Access to the Support API and
>   add NewCase to the quick actions.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000233667&language=en_US

> With Summer '16, Communities built with templates that allow guest
>   users to log cases must enable Guest Access to the Support API and add
>   NewCase to the quick actions or their guest users will no longer be
>   able to log cases

There is no other documentation around the so called "Support API". Maybe it is an internal SF API?

Either way the whole point of the checkbox is to allow guest users to log a SF case through "Contact Support".

Until there is some public facing documentation, I am afraid this is all we know.

Comment: Ok, so whoever down voted this when it was the accepted answer, can you please post your thoughts on the question? If you know enough to down vote this answer then you could contribute to the community and share your knowledge rather than a drive by down vote.

Comment: To me the OP was asking what is the Support API there is no such thing as the support API. And the answer was just showing a Google search to the exact summer '16 release notes. So the original question is, what is the Support API. Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: @JodieM - Thats was the point of the answer. There is not really any information out there and it was clearly stated. Better to have an answer pointing to documentation with quotes and confirming this is all we really have than no answer at all? Have you ever had a question where you could not find any information and a confirmation that what you know is all there is to know satisfies your curiosity?

Answer (score 3):

There are several Salesforce articles on this topic.

Support API is a buzzword for Create access to Case.

Guest User require both "Guest access to Support API" and Create access to Case to be able to create Case

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/community_setup.htm

> From the Site Detail section, click Edit. Ensure that Guest Access to
> the Support API is checked. Guest access to support API
>
> (For Case Management feature only) Ensure that the desired Quick
> Actions are selected. The global quick action determines which fields
> display when creating a case.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313406&type=1&mode=1

> Communities built with templates that allow guest Users to log Cases
> must enable 'Guest Access to the Support API' and then add 'NewCase'
> to the quick actions, or their guest Users will no longer be able to
> log Cases.